# How to compare stream records in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I have written below code to read avro schema records from Kafka topic. I have taken .avsc and generate a class(paymentengine) using maven and reading record with SpecificAvroRecord. I am able to read these records successfully. Now, I need to do some validation on these records and insert these records into a table.

```
package com.example.consumer;


import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;


import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PayKafkaSpecifcAvro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // setting properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

        //name topic
        String topic = "pengine";

        // create the consumer
        KafkaConsumer<String, pengine> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, pengine>(props);

        //subscribe to topic
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic));

        System.out.println("Waiting for the data...");

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, pengine> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, pengine> record : records) {

                System.out.println(record.value());
                System.out.println((record.value().getVcp()));


                consumer.commitSync();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

As the output is in JSON format, how can I convert it into a String and Compare it? I need to compare ACH and VCP value and if the values are same then have to flag that row as error. Also, converting these records in string would help me to insert these records into database as well.

**pengine class:**

```
   package com.example.consumer; /**
 * Autogenerated by Avro
 *
 * DO NOT EDIT DIRECTLY
 */

import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageEncoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.SchemaStore;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData;
import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;

@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class pengine extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3169039590588895557L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"pengine\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"tin\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"ach\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"vcp\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

  private static SpecificData MODEL$ = new SpecificData();

  private static final BinaryMessageEncoder<pengine> ENCODER =
      new BinaryMessageEncoder<pengine>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  private static final BinaryMessageDecoder<pengine> DECODER =
      new BinaryMessageDecoder<pengine>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  /**
   * Return the BinaryMessageEncoder instance used by this class.
   * @return the message encoder used by this class
   */
  public static BinaryMessageEncoder<pengine> getEncoder() {
    return ENCODER;
  }

  /**
   * Return the BinaryMessageDecoder instance used by this class.
   * @return the message decoder used by this class
   */
  public static BinaryMessageDecoder<pengine> getDecoder() {
    return DECODER;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new BinaryMessageDecoder instance for this class that uses the specified {@link SchemaStore}.
   * @param resolver a {@link SchemaStore} used to find schemas by fingerprint
   * @return a BinaryMessageDecoder instance for this class backed by the given SchemaStore
   */
  public static BinaryMessageDecoder<pengine> createDecoder(SchemaStore resolver) {
    return new BinaryMessageDecoder<pengine>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$, resolver);
  }

  /**
   * Serializes this pengine to a ByteBuffer.
   * @return a buffer holding the serialized data for this instance
   * @throws java.io.IOException if this instance could not be serialized
   */
  public java.nio.ByteBuffer toByteBuffer() throws java.io.IOException {
    return ENCODER.encode(this);
  }

  /**
   * Deserializes a pengine from a ByteBuffer.
   * @param b a byte buffer holding serialized data for an instance of this class
   * @return a pengine instance decoded from the given buffer
   * @throws java.io.IOException if the given bytes could not be deserialized into an instance of this class
   */
  public static pengine fromByteBuffer(
      java.nio.ByteBuffer b) throws java.io.IOException {
    return DECODER.decode(b);
  }

   private CharSequence tin;
   private CharSequence ach;
   private CharSequence vcp;

  /**
   * Default constructor.  Note that this does not initialize fields
   * to their default values from the schema.  If that is desired then
   * one should use <code>newBuilder()</code>.
   */
  public pengine() {}

  /**
   * All-args constructor.
   * @param tin The new value for tin
   * @param ach The new value for ach
   * @param vcp The new value for vcp
   */
  public pengine(CharSequence tin, CharSequence ach, CharSequence vcp) {
    this.tin = tin;
    this.ach = ach;
    this.vcp = vcp;
  }

  public SpecificData getSpecificData() { return MODEL$; }
  public org.apache.avro.Schema getSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
  // Used by DatumWriter.  Applications should not call.
  public Object get(int field$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: return tin;
    case 1: return ach;
    case 2: return vcp;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }

  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call.
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: tin = (CharSequence)value$; break;
    case 1: ach = (CharSequence)value$; break;
    case 2: vcp = (CharSequence)value$; break;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'tin' field.
   * @return The value of the 'tin' field.
   */
  public CharSequence getTin() {
    return tin;
  }


  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'tin' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setTin(CharSequence value) {
    this.tin = value;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'ach' field.
   * @return The value of the 'ach' field.
   */
  public CharSequence getAch() {
    return ach;
  }


  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'ach' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setAch(CharSequence value) {
    this.ach = value;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'vcp' field.
   * @return The value of the 'vcp' field.
   */
  public CharSequence getVcp() {
    return vcp;
  }


  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'vcp' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setVcp(CharSequence value) {
    this.vcp = value;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new pengine RecordBuilder.
   * @return A new pengine RecordBuilder
   */
  public static pengine.Builder newBuilder() {
    return new pengine.Builder();
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new pengine RecordBuilder by copying an existing Builder.
   * @param other The existing builder to copy.
   * @return A new pengine RecordBuilder
   */
  public static pengine.Builder newBuilder(pengine.Builder other) {
    if (other == null) {
      return new pengine.Builder();
    } else {
      return new pengine.Builder(other);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new pengine RecordBuilder by copying an existing pengine instance.
   * @param other The existing instance to copy.
   * @return A new pengine RecordBuilder
   */
  public static pengine.Builder newBuilder(pengine other) {
    if (other == null) {
      return new pengine.Builder();
    } else {
      return new pengine.Builder(other);
    }
  }

  /**
   * RecordBuilder for pengine instances.
   */
  @org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
  public static class Builder extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBuilderBase<pengine>
    implements org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilder<pengine> {

    private CharSequence tin;
    private CharSequence ach;
    private CharSequence vcp;

    /** Creates a new Builder */
    private Builder() {
      super(SCHEMA$);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Builder by copying an existing Builder.
     * @param other The existing Builder to copy.
     */
    private Builder(pengine.Builder other) {
      super(other);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other.tin)) {
        this.tin = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other.tin);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = other.fieldSetFlags()[0];
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[1], other.ach)) {
        this.ach = data().deepCopy(fields()[1].schema(), other.ach);
        fieldSetFlags()[1] = other.fieldSetFlags()[1];
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[2], other.vcp)) {
        this.vcp = data().deepCopy(fields()[2].schema(), other.vcp);
        fieldSetFlags()[2] = other.fieldSetFlags()[2];
      }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Builder by copying an existing pengine instance
     * @param other The existing instance to copy.
     */
    private Builder(pengine other) {
      super(SCHEMA$);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other.tin)) {
        this.tin = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other.tin);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[1], other.ach)) {
        this.ach = data().deepCopy(fields()[1].schema(), other.ach);
        fieldSetFlags()[1] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[2], other.vcp)) {
        this.vcp = data().deepCopy(fields()[2].schema(), other.vcp);
        fieldSetFlags()[2] = true;
      }
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'tin' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public CharSequence getTin() {
      return tin;
    }


    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'tin' field.
      * @param value The value of 'tin'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public pengine.Builder setTin(CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[0], value);
      this.tin = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'tin' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'tin' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasTin() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[0];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'tin' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public pengine.Builder clearTin() {
      tin = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = false;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'ach' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public CharSequence getAch() {
      return ach;
    }


    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'ach' field.
      * @param value The value of 'ach'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public pengine.Builder setAch(CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[1], value);
      this.ach = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[1] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'ach' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'ach' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasAch() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[1];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'ach' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public pengine.Builder clearAch() {
      ach = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[1] = false;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'vcp' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public CharSequence getVcp() {
      return vcp;
    }


    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'vcp' field.
      * @param value The value of 'vcp'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public pengine.Builder setVcp(CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[2], value);
      this.vcp = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[2] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'vcp' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'vcp' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasVcp() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[2];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'vcp' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public pengine.Builder clearVcp() {
      vcp = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[2] = false;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public pengine build() {
      try {
        pengine record = new pengine();
        record.tin = fieldSetFlags()[0] ? this.tin : (CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[0]);
        record.ach = fieldSetFlags()[1] ? this.ach : (CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[1]);
        record.vcp = fieldSetFlags()[2] ? this.vcp : (CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[2]);
        return record;
      } catch (org.apache.avro.AvroMissingFieldException e) {
        throw e;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter<pengine>
    WRITER$ = (org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter<pengine>)MODEL$.createDatumWriter(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void writeExternal(java.io.ObjectOutput out)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    WRITER$.write(this, SpecificData.getEncoder(out));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<pengine>
    READER$ = (org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<pengine>)MODEL$.createDatumReader(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void readExternal(java.io.ObjectInput in)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    READER$.read(this, SpecificData.getDecoder(in));
  }

  @Override protected boolean hasCustomCoders() { return true; }

  @Override public void customEncode(org.apache.avro.io.Encoder out)
    throws java.io.IOException
  {
    out.writeString(this.tin);

    out.writeString(this.ach);

    out.writeString(this.vcp);

  }

  @Override public void customDecode(org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder in)
    throws java.io.IOException
  {
    org.apache.avro.Schema.Field[] fieldOrder = in.readFieldOrderIfDiff();
    if (fieldOrder == null) {
      this.tin = in.readString(this.tin instanceof Utf8 ? (Utf8)this.tin : null);

      this.ach = in.readString(this.ach instanceof Utf8 ? (Utf8)this.ach : null);

      this.vcp = in.readString(this.vcp instanceof Utf8 ? (Utf8)this.vcp : null);

    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        switch (fieldOrder[i].pos()) {
        case 0:
          this.tin = in.readString(this.tin instanceof Utf8 ? (Utf8)this.tin : null);
          break;

        case 1:
          this.ach = in.readString(this.ach instanceof Utf8 ? (Utf8)this.ach : null);
          break;

        case 2:
          this.vcp = in.readString(this.vcp instanceof Utf8 ? (Utf8)this.vcp : null);
          break;

        default:
          throw new java.io.IOException("Corrupt ResolvingDecoder.");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is paymentengine class definition?

Comment: I have updated in the post. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The `record.value()` is a `PaymentEngine` object, so you can use `record.value().getAch()` to get the value of arc. The vcp is same. So you can compare to them with the requiered value. You get the json on print because print is automatically call the object's `toString()` method.

Comment: I am still facing some issue while printing values using record.value().get... I had updated my post. Could you please have a look once and suggest?